How do I use the "turbo:frame-load" event with Hotwire and Stimulus in Rails?
I'm trying to fire a stimulus event when a Turbo frame has completed updating. In my Rails app, this is setup like the following.
In the view (I'm using slim here):
div data-controller="logger"
  = turbo_frame_tag "europe-calculation-fields",
    data: { action: "turbo:frame-load->logger#log turbo:before-frame-render->logger#log turbo:frame-render->logger#log" } do
    = render "europe_calculation_fields"

My turbo view does this:
= turbo_stream.update "europe-calculation-fields", render("finalize_screens/europe_calculation_fields")

All of this works properly. The finalize_screens/europe_calculation_fields partial is rendered inside the europe-calculation-fields turbo frame as it should be.
But I cannot get any of those frame load or render events to fire. They simply...don't. I have double-checked that the logger#log method is working correctly (it works as expected with a simple click event), and I've checked out the documentation, which says the events should be fired on the frame, so not sure what I'm missing here?

you probably need to have a matching turbo frame in your response to trigger all of the turbo frame rendering logic. you're sending a turbo stream instead, which updates the dom but it's not the same as navigating the turbo frame.

@Alex - that thought crossed my mind. Just have to use the turbo stream for all the functionality needed.

all you doing right now is a simple update, which is what turbo frame would do on its own. you could also add turbo streams into a regular turbo frame response if you really need those events.

Can you elaborate on "add turbo stream into a regular turbo frame response"? Or point me to documenation on it? I haven't done that before.

<%= turbo_frame_tag "europe-calculation-fields" do %> <%= render "europe_calculation_fields"%> <%= turbo_stream.update "something_else" ... %> <% end %>

Hmm. Didn't realize that was possible. Unfortunately, it still doesn't fire the event on that turbo-frame.

definitely works, make sure you're navigating the frame, you could log the header in the controller p request.headers["Turbo-Frame"].

It isn't working for me. Your code above, that goes in a turbo_stream.erb file?

no, should be .html.erb, like a normal turbo frame navigation.

That's what I was missing. Firing now. Happy to accept as answer if you want to put it in answer format below.

You have to make sure to actually navigate the frame to trigger the related events. If you need to update more than just the frame you can render additional turbo streams inside the frame:
https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/1258
<%= turbo_frame_tag "europe-calculation-fields",
  data: {
    controller: "logger",
    action: "turbo:frame-load->logger#log
             turbo:before-frame-render->logger#log
             turbo:frame-render->logger#log"
  }
do %>
  <%= render "europe_calculation_fields"%>
  <%= link_to "action", "/url" %>
<% end %>

and respond with a matching frame and turbo stream as normal HTML response:
# app/views/{controller}/{action}.html.erb

<%= turbo_frame_tag "europe-calculation-fields" do %>
  <%= render "europe_calculation_fields"%>
  <%= turbo_stream.update "europe-calculation-fields", render("finalize_screens/europe_calculation_fields") %>
<% end %>


I didn't realize I could put a turbo stream inside a turbo frame like that. Thank you
